# How to export a CSV to sql server database properly?

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I'm trying to export a CSV file to an sql server database. I checked some questions on StackOverflow but none worked for me. Below is my code:

```
import csv
import pymssql

connection = pymssql.connect(server='testdb.mammoth.io', user='mammoth', 
    password='jugular$35', database='samplelivedb', port=1433)

cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute('create table sometable1(col1 varchar(20), col2 varchar(20))')
with open('batch1.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    table_name = 'sometable1'
    columns = next(reader) 
    query = 'insert into {0}({1}) values ({2})'
    query = query.format(table_name, ','.join(columns), ','.join('?' * len(columns)))
    print(query) # INSERT INTO sometable1(one1, two1) values(?,?)
    print("query is {0}".format(query))
    for data in reader:
        print(data) # ['b1col1', ' b1col1']
        cur.execute(query, data)
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

I'm getting an error that **"ValueError: 'params' arg () can be only a tuple or a dictionary."**

Now if i modify

`"cur.execute(query, data)"` to

`"cur.execute(query, tuple(data))"`

**It gives another error :**

> "pymssql.ProgrammingError: (102, b"Incorrect syntax near '?'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")"

What is the correct way to export csv to an sql server?

Comment: edited. The thing is that if i replace '?' with ['%'] - means the query would be "INSERT INTO sometable1(one1, two1) values(%s,%s)", in that case it works but i might not have all the columns as strings, some might be ints or dates

Comment: Read [mysql-index-passing-parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031401/python-automating-mysql-index-passing-parameter) `mysql` uses `%` instead of `?`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your `data = next(reader)`, is not supposed to be there, but only the `columns = next(reader)`.
I have a working example here;

```
with open ('example.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    columns = next(reader)
    query = 'INSERT INTO exampleTable({0}) values({1})'
    query = query.format(','.join(columns),  ','.join('?' * len(columns)))
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    for data in reader:
        cursor.execute(query, data)
    cursor.commit()
connection.close()
```

Comment: yes, "data = next(reader)" was not supposed to be there. Im editing my question. Also your examples throws the error which i have mentiond in my question: "ValueError: 'params' arg (<class 'list'>) can be only a tuple or a dictionary."

Comment: @HarisMuzaffar you shouldn't edit it out, it's easier for people to help if you let your question be - at least the code part. Have you tried creating the table, and filling it in separate files? Just to e.g. first check if the table is actually being made.